# How to create a list with links, using drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a list where you can drag&drop links from another websites. Kind of wishlist...

```
<style>   
.droptarget {
    float: left; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 35px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; } 
</style> 

<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<script>
function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
 }
</script>
```

But something goes wrong...
Can you help me, please?

Thanks,

Comment: The link is not dropped

Comment: please provide fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/upkmp23h/

Comment: in fiddle where is drag event ?

Comment: Let's say I want to paste http://stackoverflow.com/ or youtube...

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle, I got two javascript errors. The first one was "Uncaught ReferenceError: allowDrop is not defined.", so I've cleared the javascript-panel and placed everything in the HTML-panel.

Then I got a javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.", so I replaced it with an `alert`.

If you put the following in the HTML-panel and keep the javascript empty, I'm able to drag and drop links:

```
<script>
function allowDrop(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    alert(data);
 }
</script>

<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```